# AngularJS Routing not working on Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

Here is my app.js File

```
var assetApp = angular.module('assetModule',['ngRoute']);

assetApp.config(
 function ($routeProvider) {
     $routeProvider
         .when('/', {
                 templateUrl: 'HTMLTemplates/BooksList.html',
                 controller: 'assetController'
         })
         .when('/Create', {
             templateUrl: 'HTMLTemplates/Create.html',
             controller: 'createAssetController'
         })
         .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
         });
 });
  assetApp.controller("assetController", ['$scope', '$http', '$window', '$routeParams', function ($scope, $http, $window, $routeParams) {    
  var getListOfAllAssetsUrl = "/api/Asset";
  $scope.GetAllBooks = function () {
        $http.get(getListOfAllAssetsUrl).then(function (response) {
            $scope.books = response.data;
        });
    }
}
]);
```

Index.HTML

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

 <html ng-app="assetModule">
   <head>
      <script src="/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
      <script src="/Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
      <script src="/Scripts/myApp.js"></script> 
      <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <link href="/Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <title>Routing</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8"/>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div ng-view>

      </div>
   </body>
 </html>
```

BooksList.html

```
 <div class="container">
     <p>This is BookList </p>
 </div>
```

Create.html

```
 <div class="container">
   <p>This is Create Page </p>
 </div>
```

Both BooksList and Create.html page are placed under /HTMLTemplates folder whereas the app.js is placed under /Scripts.

When i run the app and enter this url http://localhost:51227/ i am expecting BooksList.html contents to be visible. Unfortunately the browser seems its doing something but it crashes after a while. It seems like i have caused the app to 
go into some infinite loop and crash out finally.

When i enter this url http://localhost:51227/Create
 i am expecting Create.html. 
contents to be visible. Unfortunately in this case it is not working.
I get However i get 
Server Error in '/' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Could anyone please suggest how i can fix the route?

Comment: is this the *entire* index.html?  it doesn't have any references to angular or any scripts.

Comment: Hi @Claies. It has... sorry i didnt put them as this is assumed automatically for this question. However i'll update my page now. Thanks

Comment: what do you mean, "assumed automatically"?  the question is about the page not loading, and since the index.html has literally zero content, if angular doesn't load, you'll have a blank page.  The scripts and order of script load is very relevant to troubleshooting the question.

Comment: if that's the way the index.html looks, that's not going to work either, since those scripts aren't in a valid location.

Comment: As i said before i wanted to put the main bits only for the sake of this question to keep it simple and concise. If you want me to put the whole app contents as well i can do that. No problem. What do you mean by scripts arent in a valid location? where else should they be then?

Comment: in your example, your scripts and stylesheets are outside the `html` element, making this an invalid HTML document. they should be inside the `head` or `body` element.

Comment: Thanks @Claies for the info. I moved them back inside head element. However the page still crashes though

Comment: any errors in the browser console?

Comment: This is the problem when this app runs. I cannot even open the debug or console window. I can open it once i shut the app down. I am using Chrome browser for testing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102168/discussion-between-claies-and-sike12).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All i had to do was use this url

http://localhost:51227/Index.html#/

and this would redirect me to the BookList.

This is because the index.html is where the templates would go in so i had to use this url as a starting point for the templates to work on.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is a problem with your code but moreso Angular routing specifically and the way the angular router works.

Have you tried going to http://localhost:51227/index.html?

Since that is the page where your script references are and the angular app is bootstrapped the browser still needs to load and interpret that to see your code.  Than from there is where everything would actually be routed.

http://localhost:51227/index.html#/Create would load Create.html into your ng-vew directive on your index.html

Comment: Hello @Stefan Thank you for your reply. Yes i tried this url as well http://localhost:51227/index.html. If do that the browser seems to be trying to load something but then it keeps on doing that until it crashes out. Unfortunately i cannot even use the browser debugger/dev tools in this case because they do not even appear.

Comment: Your controller seems to be loading something called 'myService' that isn't actually used in the controller. Better to keep it simple if it's not needed until the routing works.  If that is not defined angular would throw an error there. Also have you tried debugging in chrome? Sorry for late reply and if you got it all ready

Comment: ok @Stefan. I didnt want to put everything into this code. so i'll remove all the other stuff to focus on the route for now